# React is saying no file or directory, but the file is there and if I rename the file the error disappears

Tags: reactjs

So I have this react app and in one component I have an import:

> ```
> import ExportTableTransactions from '../../../modal/InventoryVarianceSummary/ExportTableTransactions';
> ```

This gives me Failed to compile error:

```
./src/components/modal/InventoryVarianceSummary/ExportTableTransactions
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\Documents\tonton\Mobile Optima\reports\tarkie-reports-frontend\src\components\modal\InventoryVarianceSummary\ExportTableTransactions'
```

Now the weird thing is if I rename my file and update my import it now works:

```
import ExportTableTransactions from '../../../modal/InventoryVarianceSummary/ExportTableTransactions_test';
```

So here I change the file name from ExportTableTransactions to ExportTableTransactions_test and is now working..

What might cause this...

Comment: removing cache files usually helps in these weird situations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: this is long time I ago, but IIRC, this happened because I renamed the file manually whereas I should be using:

```
 git mv
```

every time you manually rename a file, git will recognize it as deleting the file and creating a new one (losing all history)

my problem in this case is I renamed the file and made one letter uppercase, git will not recognize any change this way..